# Front panel vs rear panel connector

Tags: connector

I'm tryng to select a [Bulgin Buccanneer power connector](http://www.bulgin.com/products/circular-power-connectors/standard.html?limit=18), and the panel-mounted ones come in "Front Panel" and "Rear Panel" varieties. Why is there a distinction?

I'm struggling, because I need a connector to fit on a panel that's on the side...!

Comment: If you rotated your panel through 90 degrees, would that make your choice easier?

Comment: @Andyaka :-) definitely! But which way? If I rotate the wrong axis, I might end up with needing a "top-panel" connector, and they don't do those either! Of course, if I rotate by 180 (in any axis) then front becomes back, and the problem goes away - but I still feel there's ... more ... to it ....?

Comment: Are front panel ones prettier? Rear panel ones stick out less? Why not just use your unit sideways?

Comment: @Neil_UK I don't know! Those are all great questions - that's why I'm asking. I haven't bought them yet, and I can't tell if it's a stupid aesthetic thing or a critical feature, and I'm not going to waste money finding out. Bulgin are clearly proud enough of the concept to manufacture two distinct models, and they must think it's so obvious that it needs no further explanation! I'm sort of hoping some Connector Expert - maybe Lord Bulgin himself! - for whom this front/rear distinction is kindergarten stuff, can shine the Light of Understanding upon us!

Comment: @SusanW FWIW, front seem to fit in a 27mm hole, and can stick 10 to 20mm depending on number of ways, rear fit in a 35mm hole, and stick out 11mm.

Comment: I think it's just that front panel is supposed to look nicer (and is probably a bit more expensive - or less sturdy - there has to be some inconvenient). This is not a very common distinction between versions of the same connector, though, so you might want to contact the manufacturer directly to find out why they have these two versions.

Comment: @dim Ok, good idea - ok, I've just contacted them, and invited them to post an answer here. The guy at RS didn't know. Maybe the rear one has a crappier "who cares nobody will ever see it" appearance. Or the front one is inscribed with promotional messages from Bulgin commercial partners, and occasionally redirects you to their website. Or am I confusing with Belkin? :-)

Comment: @SusanW In addition to Neil_UK's point about the diameter, it looks like the front panel version has a locating/anti-rotation pin which could be located in an indent on the reverse of the panel so it isn't visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a case of *"does it mount to the panel from the inside (Rear) or outside (Front)?"*, not *"is the panel on the front or rear of the box"*!

The rear panel-mount part installs from inside the box and has the jam nut on the outside of the case; the front panel one installs from the outside of the box and has the jam nut on the inside... It is that simple.

Comment: Ahh, now this sounds like a *remarkably* good answer. That ... would explain ... everything ...! Front. Rear. Of course. Nothing to do with using crappy or unsightly materials then. Thank you.

Comment: Oh god.... Usually, they use "front-*mounting*" and "rear-*mounting*" terms. This would have been much less confusing. Anyway, +1.

Comment: And I've just had a nice reply from Bulgin, *confirming your answer as correct*. Regarding the front-mounting one, they add "As the majority of the connector would be protruding through the front of the hole, this could be used in applications where space behind the panel/inside the box is very restricted." So, cool. Time to get the credit card out :-)

Answer (score 3):

Bulgin has uploaded a video demonstrating the difference between the two types - [Rear vs Front Panel Mount Connectors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGSKQVJPlmM)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome! Ok, well, I *like* Bulgin - they were responsive at the time and now they've answered the question forever. And the connectors I bought were just lovely - at the time, I'd spent several days fitting miserable little dupont connectors to stepper-motor extension leads, and when the Bulgin parts arrived, I realized I'd forgotten how good grown-up "industrial automation" components can be compared to "hobby-grade"... :-)